# Graph SDK V5 - Is there a way to access the Error.Innererror.Code in the ODataError

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am currently converting to the new Graph SDK, and one of the changes is that they are not throwing an ODataError instead of ServiceException.

I have a case were I am receiving the following response, but once I deserialise it into an ODataError I cannot find a way to access the Error.InnerError.Code

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "BadRequest",
        "innerError": {
            "message": "",
            "code": "ChannelNameAlreadyExist",
            "innerError": {},
            "date": "2023-05-08T15:09:08",
            "request-id": "3c47704d-4e2b-4425-bc3e-715855b826a4",
            "client-request-id": "3c47704d-4e2b-4425-bc3e-715855b826a4"
        }
    }
}
```

So is there a way to do so? since the only thing that came to mind is to create my own class and deserialise to it instead of the ODataError

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `AdditionalData` of `ODataError.Error.Innererror`.

```
try
{
    // your code
    var result = await graphClient.Teams["{team-id}"].Channels.PostAsync(requestBody);
}
catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    var code = odataError.Error.Code;
    var message = odataError.Error.Message;

    // code and message of inner code
    odataError.Error.Innererror?
     .AdditionalData?.TryGetValue("code", out var innerCode);
    odataError.Error.Innererror?
     .AdditionalData?.TryGetValue("message", out var innerMessage);
}
```

Resource:

[Error handling](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#error-handling)

Comment: Tried this, but unfortunately the ChannelNameAlreadyExist is no in the AdditionalData

Comment: @Dethras Does it mean that odataError.Error.Innererror.AdditionalData is empty?

Comment: Exactly, the odataError.Error.Innererror.AdditionalData is empty, but I a want to point out that I am not in the point of catching a thrown exception, I am currently in a delegatedhandler and all I have at the moment is an HttpResponseMessage, which inside of it there is the error (the one that I pasted in the question)